# Magento2 : Get translation for multiple languages

Tags: magento2, i18n, translation-dictionaries

I have a Magento 2 with a multiple website/store/storeview setup.
Now I want to create a list of links with the text "Continue on [store_name] store". The problem is that I want to translate it in the language of the [store_name].

If I use the __() function all labels are p.e. in English or French, ...

My question is: how can I get a specific translation for a specific language that is not the current one?

So far I found some code:

```
$this->_dictionary->getDictionary($lang_code)['This is the string' . $store->getName()]
```

But this doesn't seem to work. The getDictionary($lang_code) is empty.